# using Solr with IIS

Tags: apache, iis, asp-classic, solr

We are going to use solr as our search server but as you know solr is based on java and apache server and our database is MSSQL and our webserver is IIS. Could you possible suggest me the best way to incorporate java apache asp.net and IIS?

Best

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot deploy Solr inside IIS because it requires a servlet container. Instead you can deploy solr in any one of the below servelt containers

- Glassfish
- JBoss
- Jetty (default, included into solr package)
- Resin
- Tomcat
- Weblogic
- WebSphere

You can find the in-depth details about each deployment here [SolrInstall](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrInstall#Servlet_Container_or_Environment_Specific_Tips)

Then you can communicate with solr from .net using either one of these drivers(clients)

- [solrnet](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/)
- [SolrSharp](http://solrsharp.codeplex.com/)

You dont need to worry about IIS at all.

Comment: thanks so much, so you mean that I can control solr via solrnet???

Comment: What should I do when the hosts of my servers only support IIS?

Comment: @Mersad `What should I do when the hosts of my servers only support IIS?`, no way as i know. solr must be deployed in servlet container, and IIS not one of it. so you are out of luck...

Comment: `so you mean that I can control solr via solrnet`, like sql drivers to  play with mssql, you can pretty much do everything with solrnet.  remember if you mean controlling as stop/start/admin tasks, then no. you cannot do that with solrnet. That can only be done in servlet container

Answer (score 0):

https://bitnami.com/stack/solr

It's an installer. And Bitnami soooo rocks for doing this! Just tried a bunch of different things...

Using Web Platform Installer to install Zoo, which does Solr through IIS. It's bugged out.

Jetty doesn't install as a service

Tried running Tomcat 8 with their IIS connector (acts as a filter you can set an app to). Configuration was insane. Missing files from the connector.

Found that as my last search, and it's awesome!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should set up your application.

1. Host Solr in Tomcat.
2. Use DataImportHandler to feed data from MSSQL to Solr.
3. From your ASP application talk to the Solr via HTTP. (Write some helper classes for this)
4. Parse the JSON response using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq library.
5. The best practice is that you get the document IDs from Solr and fetch the other information from MSSQL.

I have configured this set up in a large e-commerce site and supported site search, search suggestions, search refinements (using facets), and lot of other complex lookups. It's working great and super fast.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this one. They deploy java servlets under iis. 
http://www.helicontech.com/articles/deploying-java-servlet-applications-on-windows-with-iis/