# Drupal Solr search error and IIS

Tags: iis, drupal, solr

I recently migrated a Drupal web site and its sqldump into a IIS hosted version of the website. Everything looks as it should and all its contents are in place. My problem is I discovered Solr does not work on IIS. the main search module for the web site uses solr for searching contents. When I try to search I get the following message:

An error occurred while trying to search with Solr: "0" Status: Request failed: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it..

I have looked at this but I am not clearly understanding how I would put this in place for the drupal site to function properly. 
[using Solr with IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868342/using-solr-with-iis)

Please help.